# How to provide sftp password through Java

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSCH API to invoke shell commands from java. I am trying to invoke sftp command like this :

```
Channel channel = (ChannelShell)getSession().openChannel("shell");
channel.connect();
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());
out.println("#!/bin/bash");
out.println("sftp akumar@sindh");
out.flush();
```

On Java console i see that it is connecting to this `sindh` server and then it asks for password.

```
Connecting to sindh...
akuamr@sindh's password:
```

How do i provide password to it. I tried

```
out.println("sftp akumar@sindh");
out.println("password123")
```

But this dosen't work out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use port forwarding instead of hacking it via shell calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the password in the Session before connecting:

```
    JSch jsch=new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession("akumar", "sindh");
    session.setPort(22);
    session.setPassword("password123");
    session.connect();
    ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
```

And then you can use the channel to execute sftp commands.

Comment: i can do that but the the problem is i connected to sindh but now i want to get the files from another server . Now in this case how do i connect to another server and get files to this (sindh) server.

Comment: Then you probably want to use sshpass: out.println("sshpass -p pasword123 sftp akumar@sindh"); (instead of "out.println("sftp akumar@sindh");")

Comment: -ksh: sshpass: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: Then you need to find where and whether it's installed on the remote machine. Connect to the machine and run "which sshpass". If it returns a path, you need to provide the full path. If not, the you will need to install it with "yum install sshpass" or "apt get install sshpass" depending on what for a system it is.